# Xcode Embed Framework Acting Funny

Tags: ios, xcode, embedded-framework

I'm trying to setup an Xcode workspace with an **iOS Framework** project and an **iOS App** project that embeds/links with the framework, but for some reason it isn't quite working.

Following Apple's instructions from [this technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-PROJ_CONFIG), I am embedding the framework in my App projects main target. However:

1. The framework gets added at the root of the Project Navigator
2. The icon in the Project Navigator is **dimmed**, and the name is in **red**:
   [image]
3. The icon in both the **Embedded Binaries** and **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** sections of the target's **General** tab, is **dimmed**:

[image]

4. No **Frameworks** group is created on the app's Project navigator. If instead of adding the framework by clicking the "+" on **Embedded Binaries** as above, I go through **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**, the Frameworks group *is* created, and the framework is correctly placed within it but the icon is still dimmed and the label is still red. **In either case, both the app and framework schemes build with no issues.** However, the app product remains in red (missing) within the **Products** group.

I have tried Xcode 9.2 and 9.3, but ge tthe same results in both cases...

**What am I missing?**

---

**Update:** I can get everything setup "correctly" (no red, dimmed, or misplaced icons) if I make **both the app and framework two targets of the *same* Project**, but not when they are two separate projects in the same Workspace.

I'm guessing that perhaps I would need to congifure some sort of **search path**, but not sure what to look for and where exactly...